# UpdateItem operation. Do not insert item on update

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'am writing basic CRUD operations for working with DynamoDb using .NET SDK.
In process of developing update operation I faced with problem that DynamoDb is insert a new item into my table if current doesn't exist.

Is there any smooth (or any) way to specify in UpdateItem action to not add a new item to the table if it does not already exist? 
(Without throwing any exception)
Or should I write IsExist() method and call it before update?

```
var table = Table.LoadTable(Client, "users");
var doc = new Document();
doc["id"] = id;
doc["name"] = "John";

table.UpdateItem(doc, id);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do a conditional write (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate) but that will dependent on how you have your table setup what is your key? You could use your conditional write to check if the other value exists, which it shouldn't since the row doesn't exist. However i'm not sure how this would work because I've never tried to do a conditional write on a row that doesn't exsit. Other than that I'm not sure of any way of doing this other than doing a query to see if it is there before you do the update and then not do the update if it is not there.